# How do I update zsh to the latest version?

Tags: terminal, zsh

I recently switched to zsh on my Terminal.app on my OS X machine successfully. The version number of zsh is 4.3.11.

Comment: FYI, zsh version 5.0.5 comes with Yosemite 10.10.2.

Comment: Run `upgrade_oh_my_zsh` in the terminal

Comment: Run `omz update` if ur partying like it's 2020...

Comment: `oh-my-zsh != zsh`...

Answer (score 192, accepted):

If you have [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/) installed, you can do this.

```
# check the zsh info
brew info zsh

# install zsh
brew install --without-etcdir zsh

# add shell path
sudo vim /etc/shells

# add the following line into the very end of the file(/etc/shells)
/usr/local/bin/zsh

# change default shell
chsh -s /usr/local/bin/zsh
```

Comment: Until recently, I'd Homebrew but I choose to uninstall it on purpose since it was messing with gem installations and it was really frustrating to find a workaround. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @CanSürmeli Homebrew shouldn't mess with gem installations—I use both it and Rubygems all the time. Homebrew's very useful and it's worth fixing whatever problems you're having with it. That said, I don't know that I want to use it to replace Apple's zsh...

Comment: The directions here aren't replacing Apple's old zsh, but showing you how to make the new version available.  The old one will still be available to use if necessary.

Comment: Does anybody know what the `--without-etcdir` is for?

Comment: @MikeLi and @PhillipMöhler what is the purpose of skipping `/etc/zshrc`? It seems like a strange thing to skip to me.

Comment: Be aware that you may need to install some softwares again (e.g. rbenv) after doing this.

Comment: I'd also love to know why this `brew install zsh` should be done `--without-etcdir`

Comment: I'm guessing the --without-etcdir has something to do with manually installing this... (editing /etc/shells to add the path to the brew installed zsh) - anyway, this option is no longer available.

Comment: that option no longer seems to be necessary. My dotfiles repo's .zshrc file with zgen is working just fine following these commands. Although the option is no longer available, I think it's ok to attempt to use the option. It just ignores it.

Comment: The option is no longer ignored, but throw an error and halt installation. The CLI flag semantics appear to have been reversed. Now you have the option to `--enable-etcdir` See: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/zsh.rb#L43

Comment: Did it exactly except I ran this instead: "brew install zsh" and nothing happens. "zsh --version" still gives 5.3 (default Mojave zsh version). Edit: nevermind a relaunch of the terminal window fixed it. If anyone wants to skip the trouble, just update to the latest Catalina, that comes with the latest 5.7.1 zsh.

Comment: I needed to use `brew reinstall zsh` instead as my mac has a zsh installed by default. Then I used zsh in the `/opt/homebrew/bin/zsh` instead of `/usr/local/bin/zsh`. And that worked as expected.

Answer (score 1069):

If you're using  [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh)

> Type **`omz update`** in the terminal

Note: **`upgrade_oh_my_zsh`** is deprecated

Comment: While this is not the actual answer to the OP, this is the answer to the question I _meant_ to be searching for. Solved my problem.

Comment: `upgrade_oh_my_zsh` is deprecated, but it worked for me. and then I executed `omz update` which is the latest command to update. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 15):

If you're not using Homebrew, this is what I just did on MAC OS X Lion (10.7.5):

1. Get the latest version of the [ZSH sourcecode](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zsh/files/)
2. Untar the download into its own directory then install: `./configure && make && make test && sudo make install`
3. This installs the the zsh binary at `/usr/local/bin/zsh`.
4. You can now use the shell by loading up a new terminal and executing the binary directly, but you'll want to make it your default shell...
5. To make it your default shell you must first edit `/etc/shells` and add the new path. Then you can either run `chsh -s /usr/local/bin/zsh` or go to System Preferences > Users & Groups > right click your user > Advanced Options... > and then change "Login shell".
6. Load up a terminal and check you're now in the correct version with `echo $ZSH_VERSION`. (I wasn't at first, and it took me a while to figure out I'd configured iTerm to use a specific shell instead of the system default).

Answer (score 5):

As far as I'm aware, you've got three options to install zsh on Mac OS X:

- Pre-built binary. The only one I know of is the one that ships with OS X; this is probably what you're running now.
- Use a package system (Ports, Homebrew).
- Install [from source](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zsh/files/). Last time I did this it wasn't too difficult (`./configure`, `make`, `make install`).

Answer (score 3):

A simple script or execute following commands in terminal

```
# 1. download (currently the latest version is 5.8) and extract
wget https://sourceforge.net/projects/zsh/files/latest/download -O ./zsh-latest.tar.xz
mkdir zsh-latest
tar -xf zsh-latest.tar.xz -C zsh-latest --strip-components=1
cd zsh-latest

# 2. config, build, install
./configure
make -j4
sudo make install
which zsh
```

PS: If you fail to build, it probably due to missing necessary libraries. Just install libraries as the error message suggests. E.g, I didn't have ncurses:

```
sudo apt install ncurses-devel # for Ubuntu
sudo yum install ncurses-devel # for CentOS/Redhat
```

Answer (score 0):

`omz update` gave me following error:

```
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

---

This is an issue with `git`, where after upgrading to Mac OS Ventura (13.0.1). `git` command gave me above error.

Solution:

- Download and install the 'Command Line Tools' package to fix 'git'

```
xcode-select --install
```

This will pop a dialogue box. Select "Install".
More details here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/254381

---

`omz update` worked successfully after this for me

Answer (score -2):

I just switched the main shell to zsh. It suppresses the warnings and it isn't too complicated.